# Searching for string pattern using RegEx matching C#

Tags: c#, regex

I wish to find a match of `*|END_OF_PARAM|ABC_XYZ_123.txt` in a given string *(meaning string starts with anything but containing `|END_OF_PARAM|` followed by a filename(which has alphabets, numbers, _ ,-)  and ending in ".txt").*

eg:

```
string input = "| AB|3|20200914-01|5| | |END_OF_PARAM|ABC-XYZ-20200914-PIA-03_05_20200914132900.txt";
string pattern = @"*/([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)\.txt$"   // What exactly should go here?
Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"*/([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)\.txt$",
        RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

if (match.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Match!"));
}
```

Output I need is `ABC-XYZ-20200914-PIA-03_05_20200914132900.txt`

ps : Somelines end with `|END_OF_PARAM|` and don't have the filename after them, such lines should be ignored.

I don't know much of RegEx, tried to learn it and get my task done but it's taking longer than expected. Let me know if any additional data is needed.
Thank you.

Comment: You could use a capturing group `^.*(\|END_OF_PARAM\|[\w-]+\.txt)$` https://regex101.com/r/F2Kl3G/1

Comment: Are you readine the content line by line, or are you trying to extract parts of strings from a long multiline text?

Comment: If it is a multiline block of text, you may use `Regex.Matches(text, @"(?<=\|END_OF_PARAM\|)[A-Za-z0-9_-]+\.txt(?=\r?$)").Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm reading the content line by line. Thanks for your letting me know how to use Regex  for multiline text.

Comment: Ok, so you may use The4thbird's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The character class is missing an underscore to match the filename in total. If you want to include the `|END_OF_PARAM|` part you should add it to the match.

To differentiate the filename from the total match, you could capturing it in a group and get that value.

```
^.*\|END_OF_PARAM\|([A-Za-z0-9_-]+\.txt)$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `.*` Match any char except a newline 0+ times
- `\|END_OF_PARAM\|` Match `END_OF_PARAM` between a pipe at the left and right
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[A-Za-z0-9_-]+\.txt` Match 1+ times any of the listed chars followed by `.txt`
- `)` Capture group 1
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e.*%5c%7cEND_OF_PARAM%5c%7c%28%5bA-Za-z0-9_-%5d%2b%5c.txt%29%24&i=%7c+AB%7c3%7c20200914-01%7c5%7c+%7c+%7cEND_OF_PARAM%7cABC-XYZ-20200914-PIA-03_05_20200914132900.txt) | [C# demo](https://ideone.com/fNEjPP)

[image]

```
string input = "| AB|3|20200914-01|5| | |END_OF_PARAM|ABC-XYZ-20200914-PIA-03_05_20200914132900.txt";
string pattern = @"^.*\|END_OF_PARAM\|([A-Za-z0-9_-]+\.txt)$";
Match match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);

if (match.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1]);
}
```

Output

```
ABC-XYZ-20200914-PIA-03_05_20200914132900.txt
```

Comment: It's correct yes, i use https://regexr.com/, if you go in the Detail tab finds the correct match

Comment: Can you just update your answer or add another comment which briefly explains your `pattern` so that others who view this post when similar to a question could also get something from your answer.

Comment: @m_beta I have added a breakdown of the pattern.